# How to create a sharedPreference class in Android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am learning android and trying to figure out the best way to do a shared preference class. This is an example of a sharedPreference class;

```
 public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs" ;
   public static final String Name = "nameKey";
   public static final String Phone = "phoneKey";
   public static final String Email = "emailKey";
   SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
```

I am trying to turn that into a class similar to something like this.

```
package pesa.sharedpreferencedemo.Utils;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;

/**
 * Created by mpan0590 on 9/19/2016.
 */

public class SharedPreference {

        public static final String PREFS_NAME = "PESASEND_PREFS";
        public static final String PREFS_KEY = "AOP_PREFS_String";


        public SharedPreference() {
            super();
        }

        public void save(Context context, String text) {
            SharedPreferences settings;
            Editor editor;

            //settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
            settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE); //1
            editor = settings.edit(); //2

            editor.putString(PREFS_KEY, text); //3

            editor.commit(); //4
        }

        public String getValue(Context context) {
            SharedPreferences settings;
            String text;

            //settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
            settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            text = settings.getString(PREFS_KEY, null);
            return text;
        }

        public void clearSharedPreference(Context context) {
            SharedPreferences settings;
            Editor editor;

            //settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
            settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            editor = settings.edit();

            editor.clear();
            editor.commit();
        }

        public void removeValue(Context context) {
            SharedPreferences settings;
            Editor editor;

            settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            editor = settings.edit();

            editor.remove(PREFS_KEY);
            editor.commit();
        }
}
```

Is there a way I can do the same for the above example, I am new to this sharedpreference/android stuff and its a bit confusing. I basically just want to create a sharedpreference class, where you can add new values, edit current values and remove other values. The code I have shown here is not mine but from tutorials that I have found online.

Comment: What's wrong with the code from the tutorial?

Comment: You don't need a class to manage your SharedPreferences, it's simply more convenient to use it that way

Comment: <http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/> check it.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an class like this

```
public class SharedPrefManager {

    public static SharedPreferences getSharedPref(Context mContext) {
        SharedPreferences pref = mContext.getSharedPreferences(Constants.SETTINGS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        return pref;
    }

    public static void setPrefVal(Context mContext, String key, String value) {
        if(key!=null){
        Editor edit = getSharedPref(mContext).edit();
        edit.putString(key, value);
        edit.commit();
        }
    }

    public static void setIntPrefVal(Context mContext, String key, int value) {
        if(key!=null){
            Editor edit = getSharedPref(mContext).edit();
            edit.putInt(key, value);
            edit.commit();
        }
    }

    public static void setLongPrefVal(Context mContext, String key, Long value) {
        if(key!=null){
            Editor edit = getSharedPref(mContext).edit();
            edit.putLong(key, value);
            edit.commit();
        }
    }

    public static void setBooleanPrefVal(Context mContext, String key, boolean value) {
        if(key!=null){
            Editor edit = getSharedPref(mContext).edit();
            edit.putBoolean(key, value);
            edit.commit();
        }
    }


    public static String getPrefVal(Context mContext, String key) {
        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPref(mContext);
        String val = "";
        try {
            if (pref.contains(key))
                val = pref.getString(key, "");
            else
                val = "";
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return val;
    }

    public static int getIntPrefVal(Context mContext, String key) {
        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPref(mContext);
        int val = 0;
        try {
        if(pref.contains(key)) val = pref.getInt(key, 0);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return val;
    }

    public static Long getLongPrefVal(Context mContext, String key) {
        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPref(mContext);
        Long val = null;
        try{
        if(pref.contains(key)) val = pref.getLong(key, 0);
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        return val;
    }

    public static boolean getBooleanPrefVal(Context mContext, String key) {
        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPref(mContext);
        boolean val = false;
        try{
        if(pref.contains(key)) val = pref.getBoolean(key, false);

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return val;
    }


    public static boolean containkey(Context mContext,String key)
    {
        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPref(mContext);
        return pref.contains(key);
    } 

    public static void saveTestScreens(Context mContext, String key,
            String value) {
        Editor edit = getSharedPref(mContext).edit();
        edit.putString(key, value);
        edit.commit();
    }

    public static String getTestScreens(Context mContext, String key) {
        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPref(mContext);
        String val = "";
        if (pref.contains(key))
            val = pref.getString(key, "");
        else
            val = "";
        return val;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am going to give this a try

Comment: @mpanga okk let me know for further assistance and if it helps you upto some extent then please accept it as answer and upvote

Answer (score 0):

It's a good to see that you are trying to create an abstraction layer over the `SharedPreferences`, it does simplify the overall codebase and makes it more readable. But instead of writing every utility layer yourself, you could try using existing libraries or codebases to avoid re-inventing the wheel and adapting the code-reuse principles. Just focus on writing the core business-logic for your app by yourself.

There are many libraries, gists out there on `github` that you can easily use. [TinyDB](https://github.com/kcochibili/TinyDB--Android-Shared-Preferences-Turbo) is one such for SharedPreferences abstraction layer that I happen to use and it has worked really well, so far. If you want even more advanced functionality, try searching for `RxJava` based abstraction layer over the `SharedPreferences`, I am sure you will find many.

Comment: Looking into TinyDb